# Visual Studio 2013 - where is windows.h?

Tags: c++, windows, header, location

I've MS Visual Studio 2013 Professional version installed under Windows 10. But for development, I'm using Eclipse along with CMake. Strange mix, yes.

Still, I'd rather using Eclipse, I find it quite useful. Hence, when I do a simple

```
#include <windows.h>
```

CDT won't find it. I've searched along the entire C: hard disk, and Windows does not find this windows.h.

Anyone knows where is this file located?

Comment: Please don't state that you have *"searched along the entire C: hard disk"* if you meant to say, that you have manually checked some locations. Use a file manager (e.g. Windows File Explorer) to search the entire drive.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable. I used the Windows File Explorer with no results. I used Cygwin's find command from C:\ with no results. Maybe it is not enough for you, but still. Anyway, this question had a lot of more answers, where are they?